# Why are my auto-complete suggestions so bad?

Tags: text-editor, auto-correct

When I'm typing into a text entry field, the auto-complete suggestions I get are much worse than they used to be (they have never worked well on this phone, but have worked great on previous Android phones).  For example, if I enter "Th", my suggestions are "Rh" and "Therock", rather than "The".  The only suggestions that seem valid are names out of my address book.

Any ideas?  I've turned on all the auto-complete settings, but the suggestions are still terrible.  I'm using a Nexus One running 2.3.4.

Comment: Are you using the standard keyboard, or some third party keyboard?

Comment: The standard keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in the 2.3.4 update. It is being tracked [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18716).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution, I suggest downloading a third party keyboard.  I'm 95% sure each keyboard has its own dictionary.  I use [Go Keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard&hl=en), which I prefer over the stock Android keyboard anyway, based on the larger letters and the period that doesn't hog most of the space where the keyboard should be.

Comment: I agree with user Chance, find a third party keyboard with better autocomplete. However, I strongly suggest using a different third party keyboard than GO Keyboard. Go Keyboard is basically adware as far as I can tell, having downloaded it myself. Make sure you do your research.

Comment: @VRR, I agree with you now about Go products.